# Update glossary-tree.sty

Tags: glossaries

I am using Tex Live 2015, and I am trying to produce a glossary using the glossaries package. The style that I am trying to use is `alttree`. In order to use this you need to define the width of the longest glossary entry, however I have seen that in a recent update a command has been defined to automatically find the widest element: `\glsfindwidesttoplevelname`. Unfortunately despite having updated all packages in TeX Live, I still obtain the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.339 \glsfindwidesttoplevelname
```

When looking in the install location of the glossaries style file, it appears that my `glossary-tree.sty` file was last updated in January this year. How does one update this style file?

Comment: It's bundled with the `glossaries` package, so it should automatically update with `glossaries`. Check the version number in your `.log` file. (Search for the line that starts `Package: glossary-tree`) It needs to be at least v4.22 for that command.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Thank you for your comment, I am looking at the log file now, and it seems that I only have version 4.21. This is the latest version according to TeX Live Manager!